# Accessing outer response data in nested $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pardon as I am new to AngularJS.

I have the following nested $http call,

```
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: host1,
    params: {
      'format': 'json',
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: response.data[i]['url'] + "packet-trace/base",
        params: {
          'format': 'json',
        }
      }).then(function successCallback(response2) {

        //Retrieve some information from first $http call
        var doSomething =  response.data[i]['information'];
        var doSomething2 = doSomething + response2.data['information'];

      }, function errorCallback(response2) {
        //Error
      });
    }

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      //Error
  });
```

I need to retrieve data from the first $http call, and then retrieve data from the $http, and use both of these data as part of my logic. However, I am unable to access the data from the first $http call. The loop counter 'i' always equal the length of response.data.

How can I access the first the data of $http call?

Additionally, are there any specific coding conventions or specific API I can use to call $http sequentially? Nesting $http calls gets messy and difficult to maintain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because the loop probably has finished iterating before the AJAX call succeeds. At this stage `i` will obviously equal `response.data.length`.

You could capture the value outside the AJAX call and then use it in the `success` callback so that you don't depend on the `i` variable inside the callback:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    // Capture the value you need here
    var someValue = response.data[i]['information'];

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: response.data[i]['url'] + "packet-trace/base",
        params: {
            'format': 'json',
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response2) {
        // Use the captured value from the first call here
        var doSomething =  someValue;
        var doSomething2 = doSomething + response2.data['information'];
    }, function errorCallback(response2) {
        //Error
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that too. However, the same thing occurred, it was only able to retrieve the last value.

Comment: If you put a `console.log(someValue);` just after capturing the value and before sending the AJAX request in the loop, do you see the correct values on each iteration?

Comment: Yes, I can see the individual values, but once it's inside the second AJAX call, it vanishes, pointing towards the last value.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because of asynchronous nature of javascript. I suggest using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for your use case. May look a bit complex, but once you understand async concepts, it is breeze to use.   This what you can do:

```
async.waterfall(
 [
   function(callback){
     $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: host1,
       params: {
        'format': 'json',
       }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      callback(null, response);
    });
   },
   function(callback, response){
     async.times(response.data.length, function(i,next){
       $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: response.data[i]['url'] + "packet-trace/base",
        params: {
        'format': 'json',
       }
       }).then(function successCallback(response2) {

       //Retrieve some information from first $http call
       var doSomething =  response.data[i]['information'];
       var doSomething2 = doSomething + response2.data['information'];
       next(null,doSomething, doSomething2);

     }, function errorCallback(err) {
       next(err, null);
       });
     }); 
   }
 ], 
 function(err,doSomethingArr, doSomething2Arr){
    // get your arrays here

});
```